# How do I stop eps files automatically converting to PDFs?

Tags: pdf, default-settings, eps

a while ago I think I may have inadvertently changed a setting and now I'm finding all my eps files have converted to PDFs. This happens with new files too, even if I download or re-save. Could anyone please help me with a fix?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SuperUser! Your question is extremely vague as-is. [Edit it](https://superuser.com/posts/1225246/edit) to add more information about your problem. What software do you use to create and save EPS files? What settings do you think could have caused this? What do you mean by "download or re-save"? Without such information it is unlikely that anyone can help you.

Comment: I think what you mean is that the files with an .eps extension had a type of icon and were opening by default with some Program1. And after something changed, there .eps files now have a different icon (probably the PDF icon) and open with a PDF related program? Is this correct?

Comment: Edi - you are correct. After a setting changed, all .eps files now have a .pdf icon.

Comment: I use Indesign for my artwork and have tried and failed to save .eps files - they have all defaulted in their directories to .pdfs. 
This means I cannot use .eps files for any of my artwork, or share with other users, because they're now PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Files do not automatically convert.

What you are seeing is the result of your computer having been told that the same program (Probably Adobe Reader or similar) should open both PDF files and EPS files.

The way to correct this is to right-click on an EPS file, select **Open with...**, then select the program you wish to open the EPS files with and check **Always use this program to open eps files**.

Note, if **Open With** opens another context menu, you MUST select "Choose another program". The "Always use this program..." option you want to use will be in that new dialog that comes up after you select "Always use this program...".