# Another instance of EPS files converting to PDFs

Tags: macos, pdf, gimp, adobe-indesign, eps

I am having the same problem as was asked as *[How do I stop eps files automatcially converting to PDFs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1225246/how-do-i-stop-eps-files-automatically-converting-to-pdfs)*.

YES, files do automatically convert—I have clicked on an EPS attachment to an e-mail and when it goes onto my Mac (10.8.5, which I use with Adobe CS4—I do NOT subscribe to newer versions), it converted to a PDF without me doing anything.

I renamed it with an extension of .eps (which automatically became .eps.pdf), opened it in GIMP, and tried to save as an EPS—the option was not there, which is when I started pulling hair and researching.  Help!

I am thinking of putting it onto a flash drive (drag and drop if it downloads properly on my newer Mac, 10.12) and see if I can just drag it onto the desktop and/or open it without conversion.

I NEED a vector file of this logo for placing in a poster created in InDesign.  The EPS file is 2.2 Mb; the PDF is 14.xKb, so something—a lot!—is surely lost!

I am not working in Office, but in InDesign CS4—but this is happening before I even get to placing the graphic: when I download an EPS e-mail attachment from my E-mail program to save to my computer; it does not save as an EPS, but as a PDF.

Comment: You should link to the previous question.  I was unable to find it by looking for it.

Comment: Sorry, here it is: https://superuser.com/questions/1225246/how-do-i-stop-eps-files-automatically-converting-to-pdfs
I had incorrectly posted my question there as an “answer” before figuring out that it should be a new question.  I have since found that MS Office stopped supporting EPS files in 2018, so that just adds to my confusion.

Comment: You should indicate which version of Office you are using.  Be sure you make improvements to your question by editing it instead of submitting comments.

Comment: What e-mail client are you using? It may also be a good idea to delete your "answer" on the other question

Comment: Do you normally see file extensions on your files?

Comment: Yes, I do, and I think the issue is that the computer was opening the file in Preview—but then GIMP 2.8 did not recognize the EPS format—trying that again.